# How can I use HTML in a field of paragraphs module

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I am using the paragraphs module. And I add a text field (plain,long). In this field I want to add e.g.

```
<i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
```

After rendering the output in browser is in quotation marks like this

```
"<i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>"
```

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Plain text fields don’t accept html.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a body field, and then edit the source - put your HTML in there

[image: How to add custom HTML]

Comment: I think this is for authors too complicated.

Comment: What do you mean @lesleyn.? Authors shouldn't use HTML?